# ::LookupAccountSid API Extremely Slow When Targeting x64 Platform (Windows 7)

Tags: winapi, windows-7, 64-bit

During our application startup, we are making a call to `::LookupAccountSid()`.  When I build targeting the x86 architecture, this call is nearly instantaneous.  However, when I target x64 (debug or release), the call generally takes over 40s to complete.  Since this is occurring during application startup, the result is fairly unpleasant as it will appear to the user that the application is not launching.

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit on a Dell Studio XPS 16 (Intel Core i7 Q 720).

Our application is a native Windows application written in C++.

My compiler options (CCOPTS) and linker options (LINKOPTS) are as follows:

> CCOPTS = "/nologo /Gz  /W3 /EHs /c
>   /DWIN32 /D_MBCS /Ob1 /vmg /vmv /Zi /MD
>   /DNDEBUG /DDV_BUILD_DLL /DIV_BUILD_DLL
>   /DDVASSERT_EXCEPTION /Zc:wchar_t-"
>
> LINKOPTS = "/manifest:no /nologo
>   /machine:X64 kernel32.lib user32.lib
>   gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib
>   advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib
>   oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib
>   odbccp32.lib /DEBUG 
>   /subsystem:windows /DLL"

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

These kind of long delays are almost always network related.  This [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx) shows a troubleshooting strategy.